# Way of thinking for regular expression

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

The text to analyze is a mail log in linux. Here is one line :

*Sep 19 14:56:26 mailserver sendmail[14460]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=[108.188.182.85], arg2=127.0.0.4, relay=108-188-182-85.biz.bhn.net [108.188.182.85] (may be forged), reject=553 5.3.0 bla bla bla ...*

I would like to extract the "arg1" (**108.188.182.85**) value which is between brackets, and the value of "relay" (**108-188-182-85.biz.bhn.net**), but I do not know where to start and which command to use. Grep ? Awk ? Cut ?

Thanks for your advies.

Comment: You made any attempt to try and solve this?

Comment: Quick and dirty `sed`: `sed -n 's/.*arg1=\[\(.*\)\].*relay=\([^ ]*\).*/\1 \2/p' file.log`. I have no idea whether it works. But `sed` can be an option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of course I try to resolve this ... for few hours now ... but I do not know how to extract two values of the same line ...

Comment: Thanks gniourf_gniourf ... I will look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract `arg1` value using `cut`:

```
$ cut -d',' -f 2 sendmail.log | cut -d'=' -f 2
[108.188.182.85]
```

To extract `relay` value using `cut`:

```
$ cut -d',' -f 4 sendmail.log | cut -d'=' -f 2
108-188-182-85.biz.bhn.net [108.188.182.85] (may be forged)
```

Both values `arg1` and `relay`, in the same line, separated by a semicolon `;`, using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS=";"}{split($2,a,"=");split($4,b,"=");print a[2],b[2]}' sendmail.log
[108.188.182.85];108-188-182-85.biz.bhn.net [108.188.182.85] (may be forged)
```

Hope It Helps!

Comment: Thanks Lacobus ... But you have two commands to execute ... Is it possible to have the same result in one line (maybe with multiple commands) ???

Comment: @Perosurac: Done!

Comment: It really really helps :-) Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `grep` with `pcre`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
Sep 19 14:56:26 mailserver sendmail[14460]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=[108.188.182.85], arg2=127.0.0.4, relay=108-188-182-85.biz.bhn.net [108.188.182.85] (may be forged), reject=553 5.3.0 bla bla bla ...

$ grep -oP 'arg1=\[\K[^]]+|relay=\K[^ ]+' ip.txt 
108.188.182.85
108-188-182-85.biz.bhn.net
```

- `arg1=\[\K[^]]+` defines `arg1=[` as positive lookbehind pattern and then extracts characters other than `]`
- `|relay=\K[^ ]+` alternate pattern where `relay=` is positive lookbehind pattern and characters other than space are then extracted

If you want to have extracted patterns in same line as they occur,

```
$ perl -nle 'print join " ", /arg1=\[\K[^]]+|relay=\K[^ ]+/g' ip.txt    
108.188.182.85 108-188-182-85.biz.bhn.net
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation :-)